# mysql 2 set of sum using groupby rollup

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a query

`select user_id,sum(hours),date, task_id from table where used_id = 'x' and date >='' and date<= '' group by user_id, date, task_id with roll up`

The query works fine. But I also need to find a second sum(hours) where the group by order is changed.

`select user_id,sum(hours),date, task_id from table where used_id = 'x' group by user_id,task_id`

(The actual where condition is much longer.)

Is it possible to get both the sum in a single query since the where condition almost the same?

Comment: What would you like the output of the query to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS list_id  
    , user_id
    , sum(hours) AS total_hours
    , `date`
    , task_id 
  FROM table WHERE used_id = 'x' AND `date` BETWEEN @thisdate AND @thatdate 
  GROUP BY user_id, `date`, task_id /*WITH ROLLUP*/
UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS list_id 
    , user_id
    , sum(hours) AS total_hours
    , `date`
    , task_id 
  FROM table 
  WHERE used_id = 'x' 
  GROUP BY user_id,task_id WITH ROLLUP ) q
/*ORDER BY q.list_id, q.user_id, q.`date`, q.task_id*/
```

Depending on your needs, you should only need one `with rollup`, or two.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. But I was hoping that I don't have to repeat the entire where condition again since it is too long.